# How to implement a query or mechanism using laravel eloquent that enables the output in a way results are sorted by multiple external factors

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, eloquent, pagination

Kindly give me some good advice, as i am looking for a best and optimized approach to achieve the search API. I am trying to describe as clear i can.

I have to create an API that provides the doctors list as output. Result is required on basis of multiple parameters, from which some parameters are directly available in doctors database and some are not. Let me explain a bit more.

Need to search and/or sort by `locality` , `specifications` , `disease`, `patient_symptoms` , `doctor_rating`, `consultation_fee`, `doctor_experience`, `doctor_gender` .

As a basic approach

```
$query = Doctor::where('status', '=', '1');
$query = $query->where('gender', '=', $gender);
$query = $query->whereRaw("specifications LIKE '%".$specifications."%'");
$query = $query->orderBy('id', 'desc');
$query = $query->get();
```

above code snippet is not enough capable to get what i need. I have to calculate ranking for every `doctor` record, with the data rows fetched from database, like i have to assign ranking for `patient_symptoms` which i can calculate based on the `doctor` appointment history which contains the provided `patient_symptoms` in the medical records.

```
$unsorted_data = array();
foreach($query as $row) {
    $ranking = $this->getQueryRanking($row, $request->patient_symptoms); // returns a numeric ranking value
    $unsorted_data[$ranking] = $row;
}
krsort($unsorted_data);

$final_data = array();
foreach($unsorted_data as $ranking => $data) {
    $final_data[] = $data;
}

return response()->json([
    'success' => true,
    'message' => 'OK',
    'data' => $final_data,
], 200);
```

Similarly there are many use cases which i can not afford to execute with the `eloquent query builder`. I have to do this separately.

On the other side, i have to implement the `pagination` with the API results. This is another challenge to mix up all these things together.

Any guidance or suitable algorithm is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: add the query that calculated the doctor rating as a subquery and filter/sort by that. But I would say to focus on one use case you are having trouble with and provide more into on that, rather than try to have someone solve every use case for you.